# как из базы данных извлечь массив

Tags: golang, mongodb

извлекаю данные из mongodb и где должен быть массив из нескольких значений получаю одно

получаю такое значение:

```
[c45b624099574c5697e8a4ad817cd5e6-0001.jpg eb2d75a781f8463dbf9fc12506295f6f-0001.jpg ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0004.jpg ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0003.jpg ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0002.jpg ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0001.jpg a21497b772424a19b508c614e47d2028-0002.jpg]
```

а нужно:

```
 [c45b624099574c5697e8a4ad817cd5e6-0001.jpg, eb2d75a781f8463dbf9fc12506295f6f-0001.jpg, ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0004.jpg, ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0003.jpg, ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0002.jpg, ea399570dfa643638a19ba6f9a8f230d-0001.jpg, a21497b772424a19b508c614e47d2028-0002.jpg]
```

извлекаю следующей структурой

```
type Item struct {
Type    string   `bson:"type"`
Content []string `bson:"content"`}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так проблема была в следующем из базы данных извлекается не срез или массив, а карта ,вследствие чего если нужен массив или срез придется перебирать и заносить данные в него